# How to get the info from a goal with more than one type in a goalCB?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I encountered the following problem: My goal definition in my action file has two types and I only know how to get one of this values from the acceptNewGoal().

My goal definition is:

`#goal definition`

`float32 linear`

`float32 angular`

`---`

and my goalCB:

> 

```
void goalCB()
```

{

```
goal_.linear = as_.acceptNewGoal()->linear;

steer_.linear = goal_.linear*15/2;  
steer_.angular = goal_.angular*45/2; 
steer_pub_.publish(steer_);
```

}

As you can see I can only manage to get one value, not both.
Anyone an idea how to do it? Or is it even possible?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57872/how-to-get-the-info-from-a-goal-with-more-than-one-type-in-a-goalcb?/) by [DIDI](https://answers.ros.org/users/4231/didi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to save the entire goal to a variable, rather than just the linear portion of the goal.

EDIT: `acceptNewGoal()` returns a boost ConstPtr, so you'll need to change the type of `goal_`.  For example if your declaration was `car_joy::Velocity goal_;`, you'd need to change it to `car_joy::Velocity::ConstPtr goal_` and then use `->` operators instead of `.` operators.

Try this:

```
void goalCB()
{
    //where goal_ is some kind of ConstPtr
    goal_ = as_.acceptNewGoal();
    steer_.linear = goal_->linear*15/2;  
    steer_.angular = goal_->angular*45/2; 
    steer_pub_.publish(steer_);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DIDI](https://answers.ros.org/users/4231/didi/) on 2013-03-12**:
I tried it before, it gives me an error. Like: no correspondence for »operator=«. And I tried with goal_ as car_joy::SteerCarGoal goal_; and car_joy::Velocity goal_; (Velocity is a custom msg with linear and angular float types.

**Comment by [TheMilkman92](https://answers.ros.org/users/60334/themilkman92/) on 2021-04-20**:
Thanks for this answer! Been trying to figure this on and off for a week.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**It works now!** Thanks a lot! But it did not work with

`car_joy::Velocity::ConstPtr goal_`

,it seems `goal_` have to be ConstPtr type from the `SteerCarGoal.h`.

So it **worked with**:

```
car_joy::SteerCarGoal::ConstPtr goal_;
```

---

Originally posted by [DIDI](https://answers.ros.org/users/4231/didi/) with karma: 32 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1